# Google Analytics API for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

I am trying to find a stable and up to date example of a Google Analytics Reporting handler in .NET. Any information on the matter will be greatly appreciated. I have searched, and found nothing that really is for current use in .NET. I have also noticed, that the friendly friend Google did not create a library for it, but did under Java. At least from what I was able to see. Does anyone have a reference I could view, or a link with some good examples of setting up a reporting tool with this API?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my basic working example I finally got.  Hopefully this helps, enjoy!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Google.GData.Analytics;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;


namespace Gongos.AnalyticsAPI
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        public string VisitsNumber()
        {       

            string visits = string.Empty;
            string username = "******** --> Your email";
            string pass = "********** --> Your password";
            string gkey = "?key= **** --> Your APY key <--  ****";

            string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data" + gkey;
            string accountFeedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts" + gkey;

            AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("WebApp");
            service.setUserCredentials(username, pass);

            DataQuery query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);

            query1.Ids = "ga:********";
            query1.Metrics = "ga:visits";
            query1.Sort = "ga:visits";


            query1.GAStartDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            query1.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            query1.StartIndex = 1;

            DataFeed dataFeedVisits = service.Query(query1);

            foreach (DataEntry entry in dataFeedVisits.Entries)
            {
                string st = entry.Title.Text;
                string ss = entry.Metrics[0].Value;
                visits = ss;
            }

            return visits;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("Visits:" + this.VisitsNumber());
            }
        }

    }
}
```